# Reading the PDB header in c++

Tags: c++, windows, signature, pdb-files

I'm trying to read the header of a PDB file in order to know if it matches my EXE file.
Is there a nice way to read the signature of the PDB file (maybe using dbgHelp)?
I need to obtain the fields of the header in the PDB file that indicate in which build the PDB was created.
thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that what I mean. and I try to write my own little debugger.

Comment: if it was created for a specific BUILD to be exact.

Comment: Every pdb file generated for a binary has guid embedded in both the binary file as well as pdb file. Please have a look at get_guid function of DIA sdk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe either the [Debug Help API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) nor the [Debug Interface Access SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx) provide access to any information that would solve your problem. About the only way to detect the build information using either of those would be to check the path of object files included during link time.

The PDB file does contain information about the options passed on the command line for both compiling object files and linking (libs, dll's, exe's) which is probably what you are looking for. Unfortunately I know of no *documented* way to access it. It may be buried deep in one of the tables available in the PDB file but I was unable to find any references for accessing it.

That said, if having the information you requested is an absolute necessity and you're willing to deal with some frustration have a look at the [PDB Parser by Sven Boris Schreiber](http://undocumented.rawol.com/). It contains a lot of useful information although it may not support newer PDB versions

Comment: This blog entry by John Robbins might also have information of interest: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use [the Pdb Inspector tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/bugs/PdbParser.aspx) to view GUID and other basic details of you PDBs. This tool uses the [Debug Interface Access (DIA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8%28VS.80%29.aspx)